# Why is my localStorage code not working?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make a div div disappear and stay gone even when the user comes back. It doesn't seem to do what I want. When I press the button, nothing happens. Not even the value of the localStorage changes...

```
localStorage.done = localStorage.done || false;
$('#myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!localStorage.done) {
        localStorage.done = true;
        $('#myDiv').style.display = "none";

    }
});
```

Comment: `localStorage.done = localStorage.done || false` - what's the point of this expression?

Comment: considering undefined is falsey, giving a default of false seems a bit strange.

Comment: It's just so that when the user comes back, it won't go back to false if it was changed to true earlier. It worked a bunch of times for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code for the `localStorage` is actually working (even if its suggested to use its getter/setter methods instead of direct property access).

Your problem is this:

```
$('#myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

jQuery does not know about `.addEventListener` you want just to call `.bind()`

```
    localStorage.done = localStorage.done || false;
    $('#myButton').bind('click', function() {
        if (!localStorage.done) {
            localStorage.done = true;
            $('#myDiv').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP wants the DIV to stay hidden on subsequent visits. Therefore, a immediate check should exist: `if ( localStorage.done ) { div.hide(); }`

Comment: `localStorage.done = localStorage.done || false;` - isn't this useless? All it does is it sets the key to `false` if it was `undefined`.

Comment: I'm not using JQuery. I made up the $ function from scratch and am just trying to make a div invisible forever after the user presses the button

Comment: The issue from OP has to do with key/value being stored as a string, and consequently if ("false") { } evaluates to true against OP's expectations.

Comment: OP = Original Poster.  Reddit lingo I believe.  But hey, check out my answer below; it addresses the core of your issue.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage only stores **strings**.  Thus, localStorage.done = false serializes to "false". The following code will fix your problem (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/SsC9r/12/)):

```
 localStorage.done = localStorage.done || "false";
 document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
   if (localStorage.done == "false") {
     localStorage.done = "true";
     document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "none";
   }
 });
```

Note, to avoid confusion with jQuery, I used standard DOM "getElementById".  You can also consider using "0" and "1" instead of "true" and "false".

While this restriction is not present in the [W3 Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#introduction), it applies to current browsers.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) for more information.  Happy coding!

Comment: I'm not using JQuery. I made up the `$` function from scratch and am just trying to make a div invisible forever after the user presses the button

Comment: I understand your issue now (has to do with serialization of localStorage objects).  See my revamped post for your solution.  Enjoy!